# Most effective way to get data from iterating JSON using python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working with a lot of JSON data. Two in particular look like this:

```
users = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Greg Harris", "roles": ["mega-user"] },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Sarah Smith", "roles": ["charger", "rider"] },
  { "id": 7, "name": "Jack Snow", "roles": ["rider"] },
  { "id": 11, "name": "NA", "roles": [] },
  { "id": 18, "name": "Tiffany Denson", "roles": ["beta tester"] },
]
```

And this:

```
users2 = [
      {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Employee #1',
    'customer_id': 1,

    'activated_on': datetime.date(2018, 11, 4),

    'deactivated_on': datetime.date(2019, 1, 10)
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Employee #2',
    'customer_id': 1,

    'activated_on': datetime.date(2018, 12, 4),

    'deactivated_on': None
  }
]
```

I need to know how to effectively iterate through them and perform some calculations.

For the first JSON how do I iterate the list of dictionaries and pull out only the 'name' of users who have the 'roles' rider in their values list using python?

For the second JSON, assuming that as the basic structure, I want to calculate a daily rate for people with active subscriptions for each day of the month. I want to identify which users were active that day and then multiple the number of other active users for that day to calculate the total for the day. The subscription is $4/month, so it would look something like for a day:

```
2019-01-01  2 active users * $0.129032258 = $0.258064516  (subtotal: $0.258064516)
```

And calculate a total for the entire month.

The users2 may also be empty so I need to handle this case.

For the first one I tried something like this:

```
for d in users:
    if 'rider' in d['roles']:
        print(d['name'])
```

Seems to work but not sure if there is a better way to go about it.
For the second part I am truly lost on how to go about it.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: You could take a look at [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) as it allows vectorized operations.

Comment: There's no JSON here. These are just lists of dictionaries. If they came from JSON, that's irrelevant to how you process them.

Comment: The best way depends on what you plan to do with them. What you have is fine if you just need to print some values from a small dataset. But if you need to extract some values in some specific format to pass to some other function, there may be better ways. Typically, comprehensions and generators are among the best ways to do something like this, unless you use some specific library like numpy or pandas

Comment: @Barmar A little confused but isnt the structure of JSON just generally a list of dictionaries, or a dictionary of dictionaries. When I google image search JSON that's what I keep seeing come up.

Comment: JSON is the conversion of data structures to strings for sending over the network or storing in files. `json.load()` and `json.dump()` convert between JSON and dictionaries/lists.

Comment: @Barmar so when I import json and run json.load() on a JSON it converts it to dictionaries/lists? Syntactically isn't json identical to a list of dictionaries or a dictionary of dictionary? Looks like the only difference is that load() takes the parentheses off the beginner and end.

Comment: JSON is a specific serialization format. For instance, JSON only allows double quotes around strings, Python allows both single and double quotes.

Comment: But the basic problem is that you're confusing representation with contents. A dictionary is a mapping between values. JSON is a way of representing the dictionary as text.

Comment: code for first file seems OK and there is nothing to change. Eventually you can convert data to `pandas.DataFrame` or put in database and use `SQL`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! serialization, new to this concept. I read this converting an object into a stream of bytes to store the object or transmit it to memory? I know a byte is 8 bits, and a bit is a 1 or 0 state on a transistor, but why is that happening? Is it that JSON is its own format and converting it to bytes makes it easily convertible to other languages? Since bytes is pretty close to machine language.

Comment: @furas without using pandas is there another way to handle it? Preferably using the same sorts of ideas from the first solution. Is there a way to make the first solution better than just OK? Thanks

Comment: first solution can't be better with pure Python. You can work with pure Python but it will need more code to write. With `pandas` you need shorter code because it doesn't need to write `for`-loop and it has many functions already created - i.e. `groupby` which could be useful in second. And `pandas` uses code in C/C++ so it may work faster for bigger dataset.  As for second file - first it would need to run for-loop and group users by date and later you would have to make calculations for every group separatelly - so it would need nested `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first file your solution seems OK and it doesn't need changes.

Eventually you can write it as list comprehension (but you don't have to)

```
selected = [person['name'] for person in users if 'rider' in person['roles']]        

for name in selected:        
    print(name)
```

---

Full working code

```
users = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Greg Harris", "roles": ["mega-user"] },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Sarah Smith", "roles": ["charger", "rider"] },
  { "id": 7, "name": "Jack Snow", "roles": ["rider"] },
  { "id": 11, "name": "NA", "roles": [] },
  { "id": 18, "name": "Tiffany Denson", "roles": ["beta tester"] },
]

#selected = []

#for person in users:
#    if 'rider' in person['roles']:
#        selected.append(person['name'])
        
selected = [person['name'] for person in users if 'rider' in person['roles']]        

#print(selected)        

for name in selected:        
    print(name)
```

The same with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

users = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Greg Harris", "roles": ["mega-user"] },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Sarah Smith", "roles": ["charger", "rider"] },
  { "id": 7, "name": "Jack Snow", "roles": ["rider"] },
  { "id": 11, "name": "NA", "roles": [] },
  { "id": 18, "name": "Tiffany Denson", "roles": ["beta tester"] },
]

df = pd.DataFrame(users)
print('\n--- dataframe ---\n')
print(df)

mask = df['roles'].apply(lambda x: 'rider' in x)
print('\n--- mask ---\n')
print(mask)

selected = df[ mask ]
print('\n--- selected ---\n')
print(selected['name'])
```

Result:

```
--- dataframe ---

   id            name             roles
0   1     Greg Harris       [mega-user]
1   2     Sarah Smith  [charger, rider]
2   7       Jack Snow           [rider]
3  11              NA                []
4  18  Tiffany Denson     [beta tester]

--- mask ---

0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
Name: roles, dtype: bool

--- selected ---

1    Sarah Smith
2      Jack Snow
Name: name, dtype: object
```

---

Second file may need nested `for`-loop because it has to run for different days, and on every day it has to check all users.

```
import datetime

users2 = [
      {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Employee #1',
    'customer_id': 1,

    'activated_on': datetime.date(2018, 11, 4),

    'deactivated_on': datetime.date(2019, 1, 10)
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Employee #2',
    'customer_id': 1,

    'activated_on': datetime.date(2018, 12, 4),

    'deactivated_on': None
  }
]

date = datetime.date(2018, 12, 31),
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
     
price = 0.129032258  # $4 / 31days
subtotal = 0

for x in range(31):

    count = 0        # count persons
    date += one_day  # get next date

    # check every person

    for person in users2:
        if (person['activated_on'] < date) and (person['deactivated_on'] is None or person['deactivated_on'] > date):
            count += 1

    # display result for one date
    
    total = count * price
    subtotal += total

    print(f'{date} | {count:2} active users * ${price:.2f} = {total:.2f} (subtotal: {subtotal:.2f})')
```

Result:

```
2018-12-31
2019-01-01 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 0.26)
2019-01-02 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 0.52)
2019-01-03 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 0.77)
2019-01-04 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 1.03)
2019-01-05 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 1.29)
2019-01-06 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 1.55)
2019-01-07 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 1.81)
2019-01-08 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 2.06)
2019-01-09 |  2 active users * $0.13 = 0.26 (subtotal: 2.32)
2019-01-10 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 2.45)
2019-01-11 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 2.58)
2019-01-12 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 2.71)
2019-01-13 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 2.84)
2019-01-14 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 2.97)
2019-01-15 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 3.10)
2019-01-16 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 3.23)
2019-01-17 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 3.35)
2019-01-18 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 3.48)
2019-01-19 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 3.61)
2019-01-20 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 3.74)
2019-01-21 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 3.87)
2019-01-22 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.00)
2019-01-23 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.13)
2019-01-24 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.26)
2019-01-25 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.39)
2019-01-26 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.52)
2019-01-27 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.65)
2019-01-28 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.77)
2019-01-29 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 4.90)
2019-01-30 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 5.03)
2019-01-31 |  1 active users * $0.13 = 0.13 (subtotal: 5.16)
```

The same with `pandas` but it would use `date_range`

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

users2 = [
      {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Employee #1',
    'customer_id': 1,

    'activated_on': datetime.date(2018, 11, 4),

    'deactivated_on': datetime.date(2019, 1, 10)
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Employee #2',
    'customer_id': 1,

    'activated_on': datetime.date(2018, 12, 4),

    'deactivated_on': None
  }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(users2)
print('\n--- dataframe ---\n')
print(df)
print()

price = 0.129032258  # 4/31  # $4 / 31days
subtotal = 0

for date in pd.date_range('2019.01.01', periods=31):

    #print('\n===== date:', date, '=====\n')
    mask1 = (df['activated_on'] < date)
    mask2 = (df['deactivated_on'].isnull())
    mask3 = (df['deactivated_on'] > date)
    #print(mask1)
    #print(mask2)
    #print(mask3)
    
    mask = mask1 & (mask2 | mask3)
    #print('\n--- mask ---\n')
    #print(mask)
    
    selected = df[ mask ]
    
    count = len(selected)
    
    total = count * price
    subtotal += total
    
    print(f'{date.date()} | {count:2} active users * ${price:.2f} = {total:.2f} (subtotal: {subtotal:.2f})')
```